# Redirect Http to Https in Elastic BeansTalk, Tomcat, Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, nginx, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot application (1.5.3) which is running on a Tomcat container with Nginx as the load balancer.
I have created below file:

```
.ebextentions/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf
```

And I added the below content based on this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/):

```
server {
  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 redirect;
  }
}
```

I have installed SSL certificate in certificate manager and set it in my environment. Now the application serves both HTTP and https request. I want to redirect all HTTP requests to https without falling into a redirect loop. but doesn't work.

Comment: How do you get `.ebextensions` into a WAR file for deployment, and how will the load balancer read that file from inside a WAR?

Comment: The file path has to be `/.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/`. See https://serverfault.com/a/822596/123651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should add the `server` part to the .conf file. The entire .conf file should be something like this:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

See [this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/822596/32351).

Comment: In my load balancer port 80 was pointing to instance port 5000, today I check the log and for 5000 request never going through nginx. So I change instance port to 80 again and it start working. For others who if it don't work please make sure port 80 points to instance port 80 only.